# Spring boot azure project gives java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible

Tags: java, spring, azure, java-19

I created a spring boot project with spring initializer and I'm following this tutorial here to setup azure. It's an empty project. mvn clean install, mvn clean package runs fine. The spring boot app also starts properly.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-for-azure/

The pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dasdsad</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myProject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I do `./mvnw com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-cloud-maven-plugin:1.3.0:config`

I get this error:

```
Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @67b61834
```

Does anyone have experience with this behavior?

Comment: Is that the only line? You should not need to access that field and use `TreeMap.comparator()` instead.

Comment: This is an empty spring boot project.

Comment: Any more lines, like a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the workaround:

export MAVEN_OPTS="--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"

It is an issue in azure maven plugin: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/2222